# not able to validate the c# pattern program

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

```
    using System;
namespace pattern
{
  class mat
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int i,j;
      Console.WriteLine("Enter the order of square matrix");
      string ip=Console.ReadLine();
      int n=Int32.Parse(ip);
      int[ , ] a=new int[n,n];
      //string[ , ] b=new string[n,n];
      for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
      a[i,j]=-1;
        }
      }
      for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
          if(i==j)
            {
              a[i,j]=0;
         // Console.WriteLine(a[i,j]);
            }
          else if(j>i)
          {
            a[i,j]=1;
          }
          //b[i,j]=a[i,j].ToString();
        }
      }
      Console.WriteLine("Pattern:");
      for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {  Console.Write("{0,-3}",a[i,  j]);

       //   Console.Write("{0}",b[i,  j].PadRight(3));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
      }


        }
      }``
}
```

output:

```
Enter the order of square matrix:
5
Pattern:
0  1  1  1  1  
-1 0  1  1  1  
-1 -1 0  1  1  
-1 -1 -1 0  1  
-1 -1 -1 -1 0
```

program is logically correct but ,i want to get equal spacing within each digits if i use {0,-3} in Console.WriteLine to print the digits compiler displays that there is more space between digits and if i use {0,-2} compiler displays that there is less space between them and  i cannot use  {0,-2.5}.
please help me solve this out.

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "compiler displays that there is more space between digits"? The compiler wouldn't display anything... it's really unclear what you mean.

Comment: Are you looking for a fixed width font in the output?

Comment: @jon skeet: that means validation tool which i used to run this C# program.

Comment: @Mort:NO,not a fixed width font but equal spacing between 1,0 and -1 as in the output.

Comment: Well rather than running some custom tool that you haven't told us about, I suggest you compile and run it using the *standard* tools...

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the numbers to display uniformly try:

```
Console.Write("{0,3}",a[i,  j]);
```